# Swift IBDesignables and character spacing (kerning)

Tags: swift, ibdesignable, kerning

I can successfully implement a variation on the following code (/function) via viewDidLoad(), however, I would like to integrate it into an IBDesignable, as is set out below.

```
@IBDesignable
class kernedLabel: UILabel {

  @IBInspectable var spacing: CGFloat = 10.4

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    changeSpacing()
  }

  func changeSpacing(){
    let stringValue=text ?? ""
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: spacing, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    self.attributedText=attrString
  }
}
```

I am almost certain that the reason for failure stems from calling the function within

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {}
```

However, having unsuccessfully spent a number of hours searching for alternatives I am hoping someone is able to offer advice, or a push in the right direction.

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: @Willeke when implemented as set out above it has no effect, I'm hoping for some hints/advice on how to better approach/fix the task.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way is to setup the `kern` when the `spacing/text` is changed no matter from where(`storyboard or code`). The `draw` method will not execute if you change something from `storyboard` so you will not see any change. Below is the proper way to achieve your goal.

```
@IBDesignable
class KernedLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable public var spacing: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            applyKerning()
        }
    }

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            applyKerning()
        }
    }

    private func applyKerning() {
        let stringValue = self.text ?? ""
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: spacing, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
        self.attributedText = attrString
    }
}
```